# Enhanced e-commerce / Multiple Impressions as pageview ruin bouncerate

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, bounce, enhanced-ecommerce, impressions

I set up enhanced e-commerce tracking. 
On the homepage we already show offers, so I track multi-impressions. According to google, the  type for this is pageview (see here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce) . But this leads to a drastically reduced bounce rate!

Has anybody made the same experience? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!
Best, 
Meike

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking to send your impressions as non-interaction events as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non-interaction_events).

Comment: Hey Brian,

Thanks for your answer, that is the solution worked for me.
But I still don't understand why impressions normally should be send as page views (according to Google) - it will always lead to more "artificial" pageviews in the reporting... 

Thanks and have a nice day
Meike

Comment: Hey Meike,  the reason that Google suggests sending impressions along with the initial pageview is to prevent each impression from being sent as an individual hit.  Since hits are limited in the free version of Google Analytics, it is more efficient to report all impressions in a single call.  Impressions are not restricted to being sent with a pageview as they can also be sent along with an event hit.  I prefer to send my impressions with an event that triggers on page unload.

Comment: Also, please accept my answer if it solved your issue! Thanks!